# An important inequality in truncated linear regression

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Before introducing my question, I recall an important inequality in truncated normal distribution. Assume $Z$ is a random variable following the normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Let $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ be the probability density function and cumulative distribution function of standard normal distribution, respectively. Then, for a specific truncated area $\mathcal{A}=[a-\sigma d,a+ \sigma d]$ with a positive $d$, the truncated variance can be expressed by
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\mathrm{Var}(Z|Z\in \mathcal{A})\nonumber\\
&=&\sigma^2\left\{1-\frac{(\theta+d)\phi(\theta+d)-(\theta-d)\phi(\theta-d)}{\Phi(\theta+d)-\Phi(\theta-d)}
-\left[\frac{\phi(\theta+d)-\phi(\theta-d)}{\Phi(\theta+d)-\Phi(\theta-d)}\right]^2\right\}\nonumber\\
&=:& \sigma^2[1-h(\theta)], \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
\end{eqnarray}
where $\theta=\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}$. A very useful conclusion is that for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $0<h(\theta)<1$. The proof can be found in [reference 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445164/is-the-mean-of-the-truncated-normal-distribution-monotone-in-mu/455809.) or [reference 2 on page 158-159](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/4356236.pdf?casa_token=M-4K8Awc2Z0AAAAA:0C0CtILm1BRvCYTB74JxAai5Hf9S2SwF0U88YbrDPylX-F9WpIsTBdNaS6q-3feTE_86sa7z4KPTuNgIgE2A-6NlRS-mKf1OWyNfzuKlhduzpbYnpVDOiQ).

Now, I am faced a similar topic in the truncated regression based on a univariate linear model. $Y=X\beta+\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.
Assume $X$ is a random covariate with support $\mathbb{X}$, and its probability density function (or probability mass function) is denoted by $f(x)$, excluding the distribution $P(X=0)=1$.
For a given positive $d$, we define a new function like $h(\cdot)$ in equation (1) as
\begin{eqnarray*}
H(\beta)&=&\frac{\int_{\mathbb{X}}x^2h_1(x;\beta)f(x)dx}{\int_{\mathbb{X}}x^2h_2(x;\beta)f(x)dx}
+\frac{\int_{\mathbb{X}}xh_3(x;\beta)f(x)dx\cdot \int_{\mathbb{X}}x^3h_3(x;\beta)f(x)dx}{[\int_{\mathbb{X}}x^2h_2(x;\beta)f(x)dx]^2},
\end{eqnarray*}
where
\begin{eqnarray*}
h_1(x;\beta)&=&(x\beta+d)\phi(x\beta+d)-(x\beta-d)\phi(x\beta-d),\nonumber\\
h_2(x;\beta)&=&\Phi(x\beta+d)-\Phi(x\beta-d),\nonumber\\
h_3(x;\beta)&=&\phi(x\beta+d)-\phi(x\beta-d).
\end{eqnarray*}
**The topic of interest is whether we still have**
\begin{eqnarray}
0<H(\beta)<1.    \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
\end{eqnarray}
In fact, for any fixed $x\in \mathbb{X}$, we have a simple result that
\begin{eqnarray*}
0<\frac{h_1(x;\beta)}{h_2(x;\beta)}+\frac{h^2_3(x;\beta)}{h^2_2(x;\beta)}<1.
\end{eqnarray*}
I attempt to prove inequality (2) by following the given two references.
Unfortunately, I failed at last. Maybe I need to find a different strategy to prove this topic. If someone can give me some suggestions, I am very grateful.