# Log-concavity of $N(t)=1-\Phi( \frac{\mu+t}{\sigma})+\Phi(\frac{\mu-t}{\sigma})$ for $t$ positive

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, optimization, normal-distribution

Consider the function $N(t)=1-\Phi( \frac{\mu+t}{\sigma})+\Phi(\frac{\mu-t}{\sigma})$, where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cdf of the standard normal. I want to prove that $N(t)$ is log-concave on the positive real axis, that is, $\frac{ \partial^2 }{\partial t^2}\log(N ) < 0$ for $t \geq 0$. Numerical simulations suggest the statement is true but I have not been able to prove it.

To give some context, $N$ is the normalization constant of a "hollowed out" normal, that is, a random variable $X$ whose probability distribution $f_X(x)$ is equal to zero for $ x \in (-t, t)$ and to $\frac{1}{N} \phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$ elsewhere, where $\phi(\cdot)$ is the pdf of the standard normal.

The question is related to but different from the following question:

[Is the mean of the truncated normal distribution monotone in $\mu$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445164/is-the-mean-of-the-truncated-normal-distribution-monotone-in-mu)